# how to open link from webview?

Tags: android-studio, webview

I'm new, just learning, don't swear. There is a task. A line comes in, it contains an HTML file with text and links, the webView layout is loaded, I display a line in the webView that contains a link, do I need to click on this link so that it opens in the browser on the phone?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String unEncodedHtml = "Hello https://nba.com";

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);

    String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unEncodedHtml.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
    String url = webView.getUrl();
    Log.d("zzz", "url: "+url);
}

public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("your_display_line")) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
```